# Why "((dynamic) dictionary).MyKey" throws a RuntimeBinderException?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dictionary

Let's imagine this simple snippet:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");

string val;
dictionary.TryGetValue("MyKey", out val);
Console.WriteLine(val); // print "MyValue"

Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)dictionary).MyKey); // throws a RuntimeBinderException
```

Why a *RuntimeBinderException* is thrown at last line?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may be looking for [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Dictionary<string, string>` does not have a member `MyKey`. Dynamic typing does not create members on the fly.

To put it in perspective, what you're trying to do is equivalent to `((dynamic) dictionary).get_MyKey()`. Clearly, the dictionary does not have a `get_MyKey()` method.

Comment: But isn't this line supposed to add it : dictionary.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");

Comment: @cid, that will not give you a a member `MyKey` instead you can access it like `dictionary["MyKey"]`

Comment: @cid that line adds a key-value pair to the dictionary, but it doesn't add a *member* (e.g., a property).

Comment: @cid To put it in perspective, what you're trying to do is equivalent to `((dynamic) dictionary).get_MyKey()`. Clearly, the dictionary does not have a `get_MyKey()` method.